# Callback return null because of async request nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, request

Because of async request "tab" is empty

I try to find a way to return a callback(tab) with a tab not empty

```
function getUserEvents(callback){

  var tab = [];
  for(var i=0; i<100 ;i++){ //page system

    request("mysite/list?page="+i, function (err, res, body) {
      if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {

        tab.push(JSON.parse(body));

      }
    });

  }
  callback(tab);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is legit tricky: You need to track how many responses you've got, and only call callback(tab) when you've got them all. It's actual bookkeeping work to do.

Libraries like async have functions for this -- an async loop, for example. You can do it by hand but their way is tested.

Answer (score 0):

Regular for loop doesn't work for async call like that.  You need to use something, such as async.whilst(), that you can control the flow of async request() call.  Here is the revised code (don't forget to install async module):

```
var async = require('async');
function getUserEvents(callback){
  var tab = [];
  var i = 0;

  async.whilst(
    function() { return i < 100; },
    function(cb) {
      request("mysite/list?page="+i, function (err, res, body) {
        if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
          tab.push(JSON.parse(body));
        }
        i++;
        cb();
      });
    },
    function (err) {
      // finish processing pages 0-99
      callback(tab)
    }
  );
}
```